# ajax with Spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jquery

Help me to write spring web application to read from a file and display as a html page

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $.ajax({
            url : "../xml.txt",
            type:"POST", 
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
               $('<pre />').text(data).appendTo('div');
               window.location.href=contextPath+"http://localhost:8080/subin.html"
            }
        });
      });
```

how to support this with spring ????

my controller class is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/data")
  public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
    return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", "Spring MVC Demo");
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody String getData(@RequestParam String name) {
    String result = br.readLine();
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: where is your `controller` code ?

Comment: @Bk Santiago here i pasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably best to not expose the real path of the file in the AJAX request. You can keep that abstract and let a controller method resolve the real path and load the file.

Something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $.ajax({
            url : "/data?name=xml.txt", // Abstract path and filename
            type:"GET", 
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
               $('<pre />').text(data).appendTo('div');
               window.location.href=contextPath+"http://localhost:8080/subin.html"
            }
        });
      });
```

The controller method that handles the AJAX request loads the file from its real location and returns the content.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/data", params="name", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody String getData(@RequestParam(value="name") String name) {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/real/path/" + name);
    String contents = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
    return contents;
  }
```

That example uses a `FileInputStream` but depending upon your requirements you could load the file from different types of location - such as the classpath or a URI. Also note that it uses GET rather than POST.

Hope that helps.